# JQuery - $(#).remove() vs document.getelementbyid().remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Originally i had a remove function like this:

```
function ViewWorkflowDetail(btn, workflowId) {

      $("#workflowDetailPanel").remove();

      if (document.getElementById("workflowDetailPanel") == null) {
             // Do something usefull here
      }
}
```

Which worked brilliantly. Yet (in the spirit of using as much JQuery as possible) I changed it to:

```
function ViewWorkflowDetail(btn, workflowId) {

      $("#workflowDetailPanel").remove();

      if ($("#workflowDetailPanel") == null) {
             // Do something usefull here
      }
}
```

But right now `$("#workflowDetailPanel")` is never null anymore. If i change it back again (to `document.getElementById)`, then there is no problem anymore. Why does the second option  keeps  on finding that div? Are the JQuery objects somehow maintained in some sort of cache?

**Note:** Exactly the same setup/data were used to test both cases.

Comment: If you've just removed the element, why bother to check again whether it's in the document?

Comment: You could try .isEmptyObject() and see if that works better...

Comment: @Pointy Good Point! Probably just to assure myself. @ Dean Given error: "that method is not specfied by the object".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will never be null, since jQuery returns an empty array if the element does not exist, you must check the length of the array

```
  if ($("#workflowDetailPanel").length > 0) {
         // Do something usefull here
  }
```

Comment: Sweet works brilliantly! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to!